# when i try to remove a string from a list it doesn't work

Tags: python, python-3.x

i'm making a spell checker in python and it's supposed to return

```
could of
did you mean could've? yes
could've
```

instead it returns a traceback error saying that the split up word is not in the list of the split up word even though i clearly state that i'm trying to remove the grammar error:

```
could of
did you mean could've? yes
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "main.py", line 11, in <module>
      x.remove("could of")
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

(for context, x is the list of the split up string)

as requested, here's the code:

```
import main2
data = ["i", "im", "dont", "yall", "yalldve", "could of", "ive", "couldve"]
inputA = input()
if data[7] in inputA or data[5] in inputA:
  x = inputA.split()
  inputB = input("Did you mean could've? ")
  if inputB == "no":
    print("OK.")
  elif inputB == "yes":
    s = ""
    x.remove("could of")
    x.append("could've")
    str2 = s.join(x)
    print(str2)
```

Comment: Please publish the code used.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It's almost impossible for us to help you without showing the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `split()` method splits a string into a list.

You can specify the separator, default separator is any whitespace.

If you splitting the string `"could of"` it becomes `["could","of"]`.

Therefore `x.remove("could of")` will not work and throw error.

Instead you can do this.

```
[x.remove(i) for i in "could of".split()]
```

Answer (score 0):

x would be ['could', 'of'] after you split it.